# Insert plot in excel using xlwings (version 0.11.8) using python

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xlwings

I am working on a project and restricted to the libraries version. I have tried few codes to plot the graph in Excel worksheet.

Sample Data:

```
Months   Number of records(mili)
Dec_18   46
Jan_19   70
```

Code:

```
o = data.set_index('Months')
ax = o.plot.bar(figsize=(12, 6),width=0.8)
plt.xticks(rotation=360, horizontalalignment="center")

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(format(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2.,p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2), ha = 'center', va = 'center', color = font_color,fontsize=20)

ax.legend(loc = 'lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,-0.2))
```

Once the graph is done I am trying to transport this graph into Excel.

```
workbook = xw.Book("PlanA.xlsx")
sht = workbook.sheets[0]
sht.name = "Python Charts"
fig = ax.get_figure()
sht.pictures.add(fig, name = 'abc', update=True,
                left = sht.range('A6').left, top = sht.range('A6').top,
                height = 300, width = 500)
```

I dont get any error but after the excel file is generated I dont see the graph.
Can anyone guide me in solving this issue and if there are any changes to be made for xlwings version 0.11.8

Comment: I downgraded a system to xlwings 0.11.8 and your code worked OK for me; Sheet "Python Charts" was created and the Bar chart added. However it appears you are also using matplotlib and pandas so not sure why its xlwings and not matplot your having an issue with. You could add the line **plt.show()** before invoking the xlwings section to see if that displays the chart your expecting. Either way I'm not sure how much support you'll get if it is xlwings 0.11.8, a release that is almost 5 years old, and assume matplotlib is the same age.